# 400 Invalid image "us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/pytorch-gpu.1-11:latest" for deployment. Please use a Model with a valid image

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai

What could be the point I am missing here. All datasets and training is done on gcp and my setup is basic.

1. Training, validation and test done on JupyterLab
2. Model pushed to a gcp storage bucket
3. Create and endpoint
4. Deploy model to endpoint.

All steps looked fine until the last (4). Tried other pre-built pytorch images recommended by google but the error is persisting. The error long is as shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     65         try:
---> 66             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     67         except grpc.RpcError as exc:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py in __call__(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
    945                                       wait_for_ready, compression)
--> 946         return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
    947 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py in _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
    848     else:
--> 849         raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
    850 

_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Invalid image "us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/pytorch-gpu.1-11:latest" for deployment. Please use a Model with a valid image."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1652032269.328842405","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.148.95:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":903,"grpc_message":"Invalid image "us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/pytorch-gpu.1-11:latest" for deployment. Please use a Model with a valid image.","grpc_status":3}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

InvalidArgument                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2924/2180059764.py in <module>
      5     machine_type = DEPLOY_COMPUTE,
      6     min_replica_count = 1,
----> 7     max_replica_count = 1
      8 )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/models.py in deploy(self, model, deployed_model_display_name, traffic_percentage, traffic_split, machine_type, min_replica_count, max_replica_count, accelerator_type, accelerator_count, service_account, explanation_metadata, explanation_parameters, metadata, sync)
    697             explanation_parameters=explanation_parameters,
    698             metadata=metadata,
--> 699             sync=sync,
    700         )
    701 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/base.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    728                 if self:
    729                     VertexAiResourceNounWithFutureManager.wait(self)
--> 730                 return method(*args, **kwargs)
    731 
    732             # callbacks to call within the Future (in same Thread)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/models.py in _deploy(self, model, deployed_model_display_name, traffic_percentage, traffic_split, machine_type, min_replica_count, max_replica_count, accelerator_type, accelerator_count, service_account, explanation_metadata, explanation_parameters, metadata, sync)
    812             explanation_metadata=explanation_metadata,
    813             explanation_parameters=explanation_parameters,
--> 814             metadata=metadata,
    815         )
    816 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/models.py in _deploy_call(cls, api_client, endpoint_resource_name, model_resource_name, endpoint_resource_traffic_split, deployed_model_display_name, traffic_percentage, traffic_split, machine_type, min_replica_count, max_replica_count, accelerator_type, accelerator_count, service_account, explanation_metadata, explanation_parameters, metadata)
    979             deployed_model=deployed_model,
    980             traffic_split=traffic_split,
--> 981             metadata=metadata,
    982         )
    983 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1/services/endpoint_service/client.py in deploy_model(self, request, endpoint, deployed_model, traffic_split, retry, timeout, metadata)
   1155 
   1156         # Send the request.
-> 1157         response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
   1158 
   1159         # Wrap the response in an operation future.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py in __call__(self, timeout, retry, *args, **kwargs)
    152             kwargs["metadata"] = metadata
    153 
--> 154         return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    155 
    156 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     66             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     67         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
---> 68             raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
     69 
     70     return error_remapped_callable

InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid image "us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/pytorch-gpu.1-11:latest" for deployment. Please use a Model with a valid image.
```

Below are some details where I create model, endpoint and deploy to endpoint.

```py
DEPLOY_COMPUTE = 'n1-standard-4'
DEPLOY_IMAGE='us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/pytorch-gpu.1-11:latest'

model = aip.Model.upload(
    display_name = f'{NOTEBOOK}_{TIMESTAMP}',
    serving_container_image_uri = DEPLOY_IMAGE,
    artifact_uri = URI,
    labels = {'notebook':f'{NOTEBOOK}'}
)

endpoint = aip.Endpoint.create(
    display_name = f'{NOTEBOOK}_{TIMESTAMP}',
    labels = {'notebook':f'{NOTEBOOK}'}
)

endpoint.deploy(
    model = model,
    deployed_model_display_name = f'{NOTEBOOK}_{TIMESTAMP}',
    traffic_percentage = 100,
    machine_type = DEPLOY_COMPUTE,
    min_replica_count = 1,
    max_replica_count = 1
)
```

Comment: To properly replicate your use case, can you share your code when you deploy your model to endpoint

Comment: @ScottB: Thanks for the reply. I've appended some details about that to the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/pytorch-gpu.1-11:latest` **container image** for importing models. However, models trained in `pytorch` cannot use pre-built containers when importing models since as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/model-registry/import-model#container-type),

> You can use a pre-built container if your model meets the following
> requirements:
>
> - Trained in Python 3.7 or later
> - Trained using TensorFlow, scikit-learn, or XGBoost
> - Exported to meet framework-specific requirements for one of the pre-built prediction containers

I suggest 2 workaround options for your use case:

1. You can create a custom prediction container image for your `pytorch` trained model by referring to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-custom-container) .

   or
2. Re-train your model that meets the above requirements so that you can use the pre-bult container.

Comment: Does it matter that the model file I upload to GCP storage was first saved as a .pt file?

Comment: I think what only matters is your final/current image saved in your gcp storage when you execute your upload.